# Obtain a OAuth2 Refresh Token to access Google Service in ReactJs project

Tags: reactjs, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, bearer-token, refresh-token

I am dealing with the following problem.

I have a ReactJs project and it runs into Google AppEngine.

I have a class that allows the system to access Google Service (such BigQuery, Drive, GMail...) using the OAuth2 token. I connect to Google Services using Google Identity Service. I am not using gapi or any other google library in ReactJs.

Unfortunately, the token expires after one hour and I want that it will be refreshed.

Into my index.html I have this script

`<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>`

I can initialize the user to get the info (email, picture, name and surname...)

```
async function init(setUserConnected) {
     const google = window.google;
     google.accounts.id.initialize({
         client_id: CLIENT_ID,
         callback: (response) => {
             const userObject = jwt_decode(response.credential);
             let userConnected = userObject;
             userConnected.ldap = userConnected.email.replace("@google.com", "");
             setUserConnected(userConnected);
             new Storage().setJson("userLogged", userConnected);
         },
      });
}
```

and I can get a token to use the Google Services

```
async function getToken(setAccessToken) {
     const google = window.google;
     return await google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
         client_id: CLIENT_ID,
         scope: SCOPES,
         callback: (tokenResponse) => {
             tokenResponse.creationDate = new Date();
             new Storage().setJson("accessToken", tokenResponse);
             setAccessToken(tokenResponse);
         },
     }).requestAccessToken();
}
```

Any help for getting the Refresh Token?

Thank you very much.

I want to know how can I obtain the Refresh Token so the token will automatically renew itself without asking the user to logoff and login again.

Comment: Had you figured out how to receive the refresh token upfront? would be great if you could share that knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that it is not possible with the client library. Google requires secure storage (e.g. a backend) to get the refreshToken. As a result, if you want to go client-only and you need a new token, you have to use the `requestAccessToken()` method which will trigger the Google auth popup.

Here are some good (albeit well hidden) docs that may be of use to you:

- From [Use the token model - Token expiration](https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/use-token-model#token_expiration):

  > By design, access tokens have a short lifetime. If the access token expires prior to the end of the user's session, obtain a new token by calling requestAccessToken() from a user-driven event such as a button press.

  So yes, unfortunately this means the user will have to click a button **and** go through the consent popup every time they need a new token. From the same doc:

  > Use the requestAccessToken() method to trigger the token UX flow and obtain an access token.
- From [Choose a user authorization model - OAuth 2.0 flow comparison](https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/choose-authorization-model#oauth_20_flow_comparison):

  > [image: Google OAuth 2.0 flow comparison table]